# Is $\sqrt[\omega]{\omega}$ an omnific integer?

Tags: surreal-numbers

I heard that $\omega^n$ (for any positive real, n) is an omnific integer, but dose this property also extend to numbers such as $\sqrt[\omega]{\omega}$ (aka $\omega^{1/\omega}$)?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not every operation making sense for real numbers also makes sense for infinite ordinal numbers.

Comment: @Peter This is taking place in the surreal numbers, per the tag, where "$\sqrt[\omega]{\omega}$" actually **is** meaningful. Remember that every ordinal is also a surreal number.

Comment: I would remind voters that just because *you* don't understand a question does not necessarily mean it is unclear.  This question is perfectly clear to anyone familiar with the surreal numbers.

Comment: What more info could be added to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean to define $\omega^{1/\omega}$ by the definition of powers of $\omega$ in Conway's writings that is featured [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number#Powers_of_%CF%89_and_the_Conway_normal_form), then *yes*, $\omega^{1/\omega}$ is an omnific integer.
By definition, $\omega^{1/\omega}=\{\mathbb R^+\mid r\omega^{1/n}\}$ where $r$ ranges over the positive reals and $n$ ranges over the positive naturals (or the powers of $2$, say). Subtracting $1$ or adding $1$ won't go beyond those bounds (the same is true of any positive power of $\omega$), so $\omega^{1/\omega}$ is indeed an omnific integer by the simplicity theorem.